# Preview for XML file turns weird after adding tools:showIn="navigation_view" (Android Studio)(Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I've been learning how to create and implement drawers into my app

Problem is the XML preview turns into a long rectangular and it doesn't show the preview properly.

Here's before turning it into navigation view:[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwj8A.jpg)

Here's after adding tools:showIn="navigation_view":[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgaLE.jpg)

I just started learning, so nothing else was added(related to drawers) except this XML file.

Really appreciate helping a newbie out here, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use tools:showIn="navigation_view". 
Instead declare this menu in your NavigationView widget like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/your_menu_name_here" />
```